# Remember selection - then redirect to correct home page on visits

Tags: javascript, cookies, selection

Our website works with having 2 sub domains (http://financial.walkerdendle.co.uk & http://technical.walkerdendle.co.uk) but we have a landing page (www.walkerdendle.co.uk)

On the landing page I want to keep it the same, but implement some kind of JavaScript with Cookies, so that when the first time the users selects a site (financial or technical) they are redirected, but if they visit the landing page (www.walkerdendle.co.uk) at a later date they are automatically redirected to the selection (financial or technical) they last selected.

Comment: sounds like a plan! Have you tried to do that?

Comment: What if a user wants to return to the landing page at some future date?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It's hard to answer a statement ;-)

Comment: Just add some information about technology you will be using otherwise no one knows what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The demo "landing page" below does exactly what OP asks. When a user clicks on a link the URL is first saved to a cookie. The user is asked to confirm this action.  When the user visits the page in the future they are then automatically redirected to their previous selection.

From my experience users prefer to bookmark pages and not be redirected this way.  Yet, it's not for me to decide OP's requirements or what works best for his/her company.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var redirect = (function() {    

    var DEBUG = false,   // true to disable redirects
        NAME = 'redirect=', 
        DAYS = 7, // number of days to redirect
        cookie = document.cookie,
        expires;

    // read cookie and redirect 
    if (cookie.indexOf( NAME ) >= 0) {
        cookie = cookie.split( NAME ).pop().split(';').shift();
        cookie = decodeURIComponent( cookie );
        if (DEBUG) alert( 'Redirect\n' + cookie); else location.href = cookie;
    }

    // set redirect
    return function( url ) {
        if (confirm('Go to this link automatically on your next visit?')) {
            expires = new Date();
            expires.setDate( expires.getDate() + DAYS );
            cookie = 'redirect=' + encodeURIComponent( url ) + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString() + ';path=/';   
            document.cookie = cookie;
        }
        if (!DEBUG) location.href = url;
    }

})()

</script>  
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://technical.walkerdendle.co.uk/_resx/images/logo.png">
    <br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="redirect('http://technical.walkerdendle.co.uk')">Technical</a>    
    <br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="redirect('http://financial.walkerdendle.co.uk')">Financial</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this looks good by when I designed it the links don't seem to go anywhere